# How to change network mode programmatically in Qt

Tags: qt, networking, symbian, qt-mobility

I'm creating an application with Qt for the Symbian platform.

There is a [signal](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1/qsystemnetworkinfo.html#networkModeChanged) in [QSystemNetworkInfo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1/qsystemnetworkinfo.html) that notifies when the network mode has been changed.

Is there any way to programmatically change the network mode?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to change the mode programmatically, because it is specified by the network you're operating in.

If you're operating in a wireless local area network, exactly *that* will be the network mode. May I ask why you would change the network mode explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

So there's apparently no support for this in the Qt APIs. I think I'll have to do this the native Symbian way.

I found this:

[How to change mobile device's Network Mode programmatically in Symbian^3](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS001647_-_How_to_change_mobile_device%27s_Network_Mode_programmatically_in_Symbian%5E3)